# How to select all children (with same tag. ex.table) except first and last with jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to get all tags (with same tag. ex. table) in one div with id = content, except first and last. The number of tags (in this case tables) is dynamic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of them (I assume you know how to do *that*, otherwise the question would be stated differently?), write to a list, let's call it `tables`, and then do `tables.sublist(1, tables.size() - 1)`

Here is the full solution using [selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...) // parse from some source
Elements tables =  doc.select("div#content table");
tables = tables.sublist(1, tables.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Except `sublist` is really spelled `subList` and it's a method of `List`, so it does not return `Elements`.

Answer (score -1):

Excerpt from doc about selectors:

> el, el, el: group multiple selectors, find unique elements that match any of the selectors; e.g. div.masthead, div.logo
>
> :not(selector): find elements that do not match the selector
>
> :last-child    elements that are the last child of some other element.
>
> :gt(n): find elements whose sibling index is greater than n; e.g. div p:gt(2)

I guess it's a good starting point.

[More here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)